# ublas::matrix_column "vector iterator + offset out of range"

Tags: c++, vector

I'm using a code snippet of my project as the following:

```
size_t col_num = 0;
for (const auto& elem : load_data){
    matrix_column< NUMERIC_MATRIX > col_vec = column(db_data, col_num);
    std::copy(elem.second.begin(), elem.second.end(), col_vec.begin());
    col_num++;
}
```

in which

```
std::map<unsigned, vector<double>> load_data;
typedef matrix< double, row_major, vector<double>>  NUMERIC_MATRIX;
```

in the for-loop, the first iteration runs normally; but the second iteration cause an errof of "vector iterator + offset out of range". I'd thought that it may be caused by the wrong size of "load_data". However, the same error occurs when I add the following line

```
db_data.resize(row_number, column_number)
```

where "row_number" and "column_number" are correct value of the row and column of the matrix. NOTE: column_number is equal to load_data.size();

Did I do something wrong about using the ublas::matrix_column<> ?

It's a rush project and thanks a lot!

Comment: Please provide [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). And my guess: using copies instead of references, target vector is too small to copy into (not using `std::back_inserter`) or so...

Comment: Well, the ublas::matrix_column has no push_back() member function, and I doubt the back_inserter can work with the matrix_column?

Comment: I've just tested the push_back() and the compiler (VC12.0) complained that 'push_back' is not a member of 'boost::numeric::ublas::matrix_column<NUMERIC_MATRIX>, where NUMERIC_MATRIX is a type described in the question. :)

Comment: Latest info: I've changed the row number from actuall record number + 1, the code works well; In this case, the actual record number is 330, while set the row number to 330, the debug check doesn't pass but the it does work with 331. Strange, isn't it? :(